# Why when setting the player rotation on x and z to 0 it's not setting it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a script, the script is too long so I'm showing the Update part only I'm checking if the game is running after a loading saved game have been done and then trying to set the player position to 0 on X and Y and keep the same value of Y.

The script is attached to the Player. and I check with a break point and it's doing the code inside once.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == true && setNaviRotation == false)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, transform.rotation.y, 0);
            setNaviRotation = true;
        }
    }
```

When starting the player first time the player rotation is 0,120,0 :

[image: Player start rotation settings in the inspector]

but then when loading a saved game and looking on the player the rotation is not 0 on X and Y even if it does the code in the Update.

You can see the player is a bit lying back and the rotation on X is -9.715 and the Z -0.99100
If I will set them on my own manual they player will stand straight.

Why the setting of the rotation in the Update is not changing anything on the player ?

[image: the player is a bit lying back]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is yo use Quaternion.Euler this is working perfect.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == true && setNaviRotation == false)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            setNaviRotation = true;
        }
    }
```